# Django and jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, python, django, datatable

I'm new in python/django and i'm making a project where i have this datatable: https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html and i'm wondering if theres a way to select multiple objects, because now you are able to select only one

Answer (score 0):

In jquery settings add `select-checkbox` as **className** As shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

Ref: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html